# AngularJS update function is (still)not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function which updates the object, the problem is when I go back from the update form field to the detailed view, it initializes the old object instead of the updated object.

**I want to populate the cars list in the CarService instead of the app.js**

This is my carService:

```
 window.app.service('CarService', ['HTTPService', '$q',       
'$http', function (HTTPService, $q, $http) {
 'use strict';


this.cars = [];
this.get = function () {
var deferred = $q.defer();

HTTPService.get('/car').then(function resolve(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
}, function reject(response){

    deferred.reject(response);      
});
};

this.add = function (formCar) {

var deferred = $q.defer();

console.log("CarService response 1 : ");
$http.post('/#/car', formCar).then(function resolve(response){

    deferred.resolve(response.data);
}, function reject(response){
    deferred.reject(response);      
});
return deferred.promise;
};

this.showDetails = function (carId){
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get('/car/view/{{carId}}').then(function resolve(response){
    HTTPService.get('/car/view/' + carId).then(function 
resolve(response) {

    deferred.resolve(response.data);

}, function reject(response){
    deferred.reject(response);      
});
return deferred.promise;

};

this.put = function (carformUpdate, opleidingsprofielId) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.put('/#/car/:carId/update', carformUpdate).then(function resolve(response){
    deferred.resolve(response.data);
}, function reject(response){
    deferred.reject(response);      
});
return deferred.promise;
 };

}]);
```

This is my updateCar controller:

```
window.app.controller('updateCarCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 
'CarService', '$location', function ($scope, $routeParams, CarService, 
$location) {
'use strict';
$scope.carId = $routeParams.carId;
initCar($scope.carId);


function initCar(carId) {
        CarService.showDetails(carId).then(function success(car) {
            $scope.car = car;

        }, function error(response) {
        });
    }

    $scope.updateCar = function (carId) {
        carId = $scope.carId;

        if($scope.car !== null){
            CarService.put($scope.car, carId).then(function 
  success(response) {
            $scope.car = response;
            $location.path('/car/view/' + carId);
            alert("Car updated");

        }, function error(response) {
            $scope.error = response.statusText;
            $scope.myform = {};
        });
        }


    };

   }]);
```

This is my carView controller:

```
  window.app.controller('carViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',    '$location', 
 'CarService', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, CarService) {
 'use strict';

 $scope.carId = $routeParams.carId;
 initCar($scope.carId);

 function initCar(carId) {
  CarService.showDetails(carId).then(function success(car) {  

   $scope.car = car;            
        }, function error(response) {
    });
   }
   }]);
```

My carView initializes the object again when it gets redirected with $location.path('/car/view/' + carId); but as the original object and not the updated object.

I'm trying to do this on an ngMock backend.

My app.js looks like this:

App.js

routing:

```
.when('/car', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/car/car.html'

})
.when('/car/view/:carId', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/car/carView.html',
    controller: 'carViewCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
.when('/car/addCar', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/car/carAdd.html'
})
.when('/car/:carId/update', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/car/carUpdate.html',
    controller: 'updateCarCtrl',
    conrtollerAs: 'ctrl'
})
```

app.run: this is where my mock backend is defined

```
  window.app.run(function($httpBackend) {
  var cars = [
  {
  id: 0, 
  name: ‘car0’, 
  address: 'adress0', 
  tel: 'tel0', 
  email: 'email0'}, 
  {
  id: 1, 
  name: ‘car1’, 
  address: 'adress1', 
  tel: 'tel1', 
  email: 'email1'
  }];

  var carUrl = “/#/car”;

  $httpBackend.whenGET(carUrl).respond(function(method,url,data) {
   return [200, cars, {}];
   });

   $httpBackend.whenGET(/\/#\/car\/view\/(\d+)/, undefined, 
   ['carId']).respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {

    return [200, cars[Number(params.carId)], {
    carId : params.carId
    }];
    });

      $httpBackend.whenPUT('/#/car/:carId/update').respond(function(method,     url, 
 data, carId) {
 var car = angular.fromJson(data);
 return [200, car, {}];
     });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why do you have a `HTTPService.get` inside a `$http.get` resolve?

Comment: all that being said, your service needs a lot of cleanup to be up to working angular standards;  in particular, you shouldn't wrap `$http` inside a `deferred`, since `$http` already returns a promise.

Comment: does the object get updated at backend after you update in UI ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 the app works on a mock backend, but the object gets updated in the CarService

Comment: @Claies yeah I know it’s not up to the standards, I just need a quick working app for now. Do you think it can work (even if it’s not up to the standards) in this setup?

Comment: Please do not post the same question twice. [Edit] this one to improve it if you can.

Comment: I've studied the code you have posted here for a bit, and I don't understand why you have a mix of `HTTPService` and `$http` in use together, and the use of `deferred` to wrap promises make it very difficult to understand where your data is being updated, and where your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your update function calls the `CarService.put`, which in turn calls a `HTTPService.put`. In your mocked backend you have this:

```
$httpBackend.whenPUT
    -> add new car;
```

So it always adds a new car, and doesn't update one. This means that when you do the get, you probably get the first car back that matches the given id, which isn't the updated one.

In pseudo code:

```
// carService.cars = [{id:1,name:"name"}]
var myCar = carService.get(1); // returns {id:1,name:"name"}
myCar.name = "otherName";
carService.put(car); // -> cars.push(car); -> cars = [{id:1,name:"name"},{id:1,name:"otherName"}]

goToDetails(1);

var myCar = carService.get(1); // iterate over the cars, and return the one with id = 1,
// which is {id:1,name:"name"}
```

Comment: oke but how do I get the updated object in the view controller? Please help

Comment: That's what I said, you don't have an updated object, because you **add** instead of **update** the object when you call the `carService.put`.